# Jquery Generate random number pass to if

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a random number in Jquery I'm not sure if I need to store it to do the next part maybe you guys could help me out on that first off my random number generator;

```
    $( "#arrowleftup" ).click(function() {
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    $('#storenumber').text(number);
    });
```

I want to generate a random number when my Img with the id "arrowleftup" is clicked, I then want to pass my number into this -

```
If ('#storenumber' == 8=>){
$('.battle').show();
} else {
die
};
```

So that if the number was 8 or higher it would show a hidden div, can anyone spot the error in my code? Also do I need to store the value to pass it into the if statement

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7t59E/

thanks!

Comment: There are so many errors in this small code that we should probably only recommend a tutorial.

Comment: Go for it I'm willing to learn, I know the die thing is from php I didn't know what to put there to help you understand what I was trying to do.

Comment: `If`: Should be `if`. `'#storenumber' == 8`: Why are you comparing a string against a number? It would never be true. `8=>`: ?? `die`: doesn't exist in JavaScript.

Comment: Start by using your browser debugging `console`

Comment: @Felix Kling, I was trying to say if the number is equal (==) to 8 or more (=>), then run.

Comment: What is `die` supposed to do? There is no such thing in javascript (apart from maybe `window.close()`)

Comment: @user2598957: That would be `number >= 8`. Good resources to learn JS are http://eloquentjavascript.net/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/7t59E/1/)**

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#battle").hide();
    $("#arrowleftup").click(function () {
        var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        $('#storenumber').text(number);
        if (number >= 8) $("#battle").show();
        else $("#battle").hide();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to store result into a dom element

you can do it via

```
$( "#arrowleftup" ).click(function() {
   var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
   $('.battle').hide();
   if (number >= 8){
        $('.battle').show();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the code in the event handler to execute it whenever a number is generated. There you also can just access the `number` variable instead of getting it from the element text:

```
$( "#arrowleftup" ).click(function() {
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    $('#storenumber').text(number);
    if (number == 8) {
        $('.battle').show();
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```

([updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7t59E/4/), also including a `.battle` element and loading the jQuery library)

Answer (score 0):

U can try something like this ?

```
$( "#arrowleftup" ).click(function() {

    $('#storenumber').text(parseInt(Math.random()*10));

    if (parseInt($('#storenumber').text()) > 4) {
        $("#toggleme").show();
    } else {
        $("#toggleme").hide();
    }

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7t59E/7/)